# Typescript: getting an undefined value

Tags: string, angular, typescript, undefined, angular5

I seem to have a problem I can't solve.

I want 'dialogTitle' variable to also display the startHour and startMinute variables alongside the title variable. However, I seem to get the title and 'undefined' twice after the title. What should I do?

event-form.component.ts

```
import { Component, Inject, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';

import { MatColors } from '@fuse/mat-colors';

import { CalendarEvent } from 'angular-calendar';
import { CalendarEventModel } from '../event.model';

import { locale as eventFormEnglish } from './i18n/en';
import { locale as eventFormDutch } from './i18n/nl';

import { FuseCalendarComponent } from '../calendar.component';

@Component({
    selector     : 'fuse-calendar-event-form-dialog',
    templateUrl  : './event-form.component.html',
    styleUrls    : ['./event-form.component.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})

export class FuseCalendarEventFormDialogComponent
{
    event: CalendarEvent;
    dialogTitle: string;
    eventForm: FormGroup;
    action: string;
    startHour: string;
    startMinute: string;
    endHour: string;
    endMinute: string;
    presetColors = MatColors.presets;

    //Shows dropdown items

    startTimeHours = [
        {value: 'time-0', viewValue: '7'},
        {value: 'time-1', viewValue: '8'},
        {value: 'time-2', viewValue: '9'},
        {value: 'time-3', viewValue: '10'},
        {value: 'time-4', viewValue: '11'},
        {value: 'time-5', viewValue: '12'},
        {value: 'time-6', viewValue: '13'},
        {value: 'time-7', viewValue: '14'},
        {value: 'time-8', viewValue: '15'},
        {value: 'time-9', viewValue: '16'},
        {value: 'time-10', viewValue: '17'},
        {value: 'time-11', viewValue: '18'},
        {value: 'time-12', viewValue: '19'},
        {value: 'time-13', viewValue: '20'},
        {value: 'time-14', viewValue: '21'},
        {value: 'time-15', viewValue: '22'},
        {value: 'time-16', viewValue: '23'}
    ];
    startTimeMinutes = [
        {value: 'time-0', viewValue: '0'},
        {value: 'time-1', viewValue: '5'},
        {value: 'time-2', viewValue: '10'},
        {value: 'time-3', viewValue: '15'},
        {value: 'time-4', viewValue: '20'},
        {value: 'time-5', viewValue: '25'},
        {value: 'time-6', viewValue: '30'},
        {value: 'time-7', viewValue: '35'},
        {value: 'time-8', viewValue: '40'},
        {value: 'time-9', viewValue: '45'},
        {value: 'time-10', viewValue: '50'},
        {value: 'time-11', viewValue: '55'}
    ];

    endTimeHours = [
        {value: 'time-0', viewValue: '7'},
        {value: 'time-1', viewValue: '8'},
        {value: 'time-2', viewValue: '9'},
        {value: 'time-3', viewValue: '10'},
        {value: 'time-4', viewValue: '11'},
        {value: 'time-5', viewValue: '12'},
        {value: 'time-6', viewValue: '13'},
        {value: 'time-7', viewValue: '14'},
        {value: 'time-8', viewValue: '15'},
        {value: 'time-9', viewValue: '16'},
        {value: 'time-10', viewValue: '17'},
        {value: 'time-11', viewValue: '18'},
        {value: 'time-12', viewValue: '19'},
        {value: 'time-13', viewValue: '20'},
        {value: 'time-14', viewValue: '21'},
        {value: 'time-15', viewValue: '22'},
        {value: 'time-16', viewValue: '23'}
    ];
    endTimeMinutes = [
        {value: 'time-0', viewValue: '0'},
        {value: 'time-1', viewValue: '5'},
        {value: 'time-2', viewValue: '10'},
        {value: 'time-3', viewValue: '15'},
        {value: 'time-4', viewValue: '20'},
        {value: 'time-5', viewValue: '25'},
        {value: 'time-6', viewValue: '30'},
        {value: 'time-7', viewValue: '35'},
        {value: 'time-8', viewValue: '40'},
        {value: 'time-9', viewValue: '45'},
        {value: 'time-10', viewValue: '50'},
        {value: 'time-11', viewValue: '55'}
    ];

    constructor(
        public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<FuseCalendarEventFormDialogComponent>,
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) private data: any,
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder
    )
    {
        this.event = data.event;
        this.action = data.action;

        if ( this.action === 'edit' )
        {
            this.dialogTitle = this.event.title + " - " + this.startHour + ":" + this.startMinute;
        }
        else
        {
            this.dialogTitle = 'New Event';
            this.event = new CalendarEventModel({
                start: data.date,
                end  : data.date
            });
        }

        this.eventForm = this.createEventForm();
    }

    createEventForm()
    {
        return new FormGroup({
            title       : new FormControl(this.event.title),
            start       : new FormControl(this.event.start),
            end         : new FormControl(this.event.end),
            startHour   : new FormControl(this.startHour),
            startMinute : new FormControl(this.startMinute),
            endHour     : new FormControl(this.endHour),
            endMinute   : new FormControl(this.endMinute),
            allDay      : new FormControl(this.event.allDay),
            color       : this.formBuilder.group({
                primary     : new FormControl(this.event.color.primary),
                secondary   : new FormControl(this.event.color.secondary)
            }),
            meta        :
                this.formBuilder.group({
                    location: new FormControl(this.event.meta.location),
                    notes   : new FormControl(this.event.meta.notes)
                })
        });
    }
}
```

event-form.component.html

```
<div class="dialog-content-wrapper">
    <mat-toolbar matDialogTitle class="mat-accent m-0">
        <div fxFlex fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
            <span class="title dialog-title">{{dialogTitle}}</span>
            <button mat-button class="mat-icon-button"
                    (click)="dialogRef.close()"
                    aria-label="Close dialog">
                <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
            </button>
        </div>
    </mat-toolbar>

    <div mat-dialog-content class="p-24 m-0" fusePerfectScrollbar>

        <form name="eventForm" [formGroup]="eventForm" class="event-form w-100-p" fxLayout="column" fxFlex>

            <mat-form-field class="w-100-p">
                <input matInput
                       name="title"
                       formControlName="title"
                       [placeholder]="'FORM.TITLE' | translate"
                       required>
            </mat-form-field>

            <div class="py-16" fxFlex="1 0 auto" fxLayout="row">
                <mat-slide-toggle
                    name="allDay"
                    formControlName="allDay"
                    class="mr-24"
                    aria-label="All day">
                    {{ 'FORM.ALLDAY' | translate }}
                </mat-slide-toggle>
            </div>

            <div class="py-16" fxFlex="1 0 auto" fxLayout="column" fxLayout.gt-xs="row" formGroupName="color">

                <mat-form-field class="mr-sm-24" fxFlex>
                    <input matInput
                           class="primary-color-input"
                           name="primary color"
                           formControlName="primary"
                           [placeholder]="'FORM.PRIMARYCOLOR' | translate"
                           [(colorPicker)]="event.color.primary"
                           cpWidth="290px"
                           [cpPresetColors]="presetColors"
                           [style.background]="event.color.primary"
                           (colorPickerChange)="event.color.primary = $event; eventForm.patchValue({color:{primary:$event}})"/>
                </mat-form-field>

                <mat-form-field fxFlex>
                    <input matInput
                           class="secondary-color-input"
                           name="secondary color"
                           formControlName="secondary"
                           [placeholder]="'FORM.SECONDARYCOLOR' | translate"
                           [(colorPicker)]="event.color.secondary"
                           cpWidth="290px"
                           [cpPresetColors]="presetColors"
                           [style.background]="event.color.secondary"
                           (colorPickerChange)="event.color.secondary = $event; eventForm.patchValue({color:{secondary:$event}})"/>
                </mat-form-field>

            </div>

            <div fxFlex="1 0 auto" fxLayout="column" fxLayout.gt-xs="row">

                <mat-form-field class="mr-sm-24" fxFlex>
                    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="startDatePicker" [placeholder]="'FORM.STARTDATE' | translate"
                           name="start"
                           formControlName="start" required>
                    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="startDatePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                    <mat-datepicker #startDatePicker></mat-datepicker>
                </mat-form-field>

                <mat-form-field>
                  <mat-select [placeholder]="'FORM.STARTHOUR' | translate" formControlName="startHour" required>
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let startTimeHour of startTimeHours" [value]="startTimeHour">
                          {{startTimeHour.viewValue}}
                        </mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>

                <mat-form-field>
                  <mat-select [placeholder]="'FORM.STARTMINUTE' | translate" formControlName="startMinute" required>
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let startTimeMinute of startTimeMinutes" [value]="startTimeMinute">
                          {{startTimeMinute.viewValue}}
                        </mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>

            </div>

            <div fxFlex="1 0 auto" fxLayout="column" fxLayout.gt-xs="row">

                <mat-form-field class="mr-sm-24" fxFlex>
                    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="endDatePicker" [placeholder]="'FORM.ENDDATE' | translate"
                           name="end"
                           formControlName="end" required>
                    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="endDatePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                    <mat-datepicker #endDatePicker></mat-datepicker>
                </mat-form-field>

                <mat-form-field>
                  <mat-select [placeholder]="'FORM.ENDHOUR' | translate" formControlName="endHour" required>
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let endTimeHour of endTimeHours" [value]="endTimeHour">
                          {{endTimeHour.viewValue}}
                        </mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>

                <mat-form-field>
                  <mat-select [placeholder]="'FORM.ENDMINUTE' | translate" formControlName="endMinute" required>
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let endTimeMinute of endTimeMinutes" [value]="endTimeMinute">
                          {{endTimeMinute.viewValue}}
                        </mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>

            </div>

            <mat-form-field formGroupName="meta" class="w-100-p">
                <input matInput
                       name="location"
                       formControlName="location"
                       [placeholder]="'FORM.LOCATION' | translate">
            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-form-field formGroupName="meta" class="w-100-p">

                <textarea matInput
                          formControlName="notes"
                          [placeholder]="'FORM.NOTES' | translate"
                          mat-maxlength="250"
                          max-rows="4">
                </textarea>
            </mat-form-field>

        </form>

    </div>

    <div mat-dialog-actions class="m-0 p-16" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">

        <button *ngIf="action !=='edit'"
                mat-raised-button
                (click)="dialogRef.close(eventForm)"
                class="save-button mat-accent"
                [disabled]="eventForm.invalid"
                aria-label="SAVE">
            SAVE
        </button>

        <button *ngIf="action ==='edit'"
                mat-raised-button
                (click)="dialogRef.close(['save',eventForm])"
                class="save-button mat-accent"
                [disabled]="eventForm.invalid"
                aria-label="SAVE">
             {{ 'FORM.SAVE' | translate }}
        </button>

        <button *ngIf="action ==='edit'"
                mat-button
                class="mat-icon-button"
                (click)="dialogRef.close(['delete',eventForm])"
                aria-label="Delete"
                matTooltip="Delete">
            <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I believe it has to do with the fact I haven't declared the two variables the right way or something like that, but I'm kinda new, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Is it the order?

EDIT: It should get the startHour and startMinute variables from the database entries, but I do not know how. The database is declared in another file:

calendar.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';
import { startOfDay, isSameDay, isSameMonth } from 'date-fns';

import { CalendarEvent, CalendarEventAction, CalendarEventTimesChangedEvent, CalendarMonthViewDay } from 'angular-calendar';

import { FuseConfirmDialogComponent } from '@fuse/components/confirm-dialog/confirm-dialog.component';
import { fuseAnimations } from '@fuse/animations';

import { FuseCalendarEventFormDialogComponent } from './event-form/event-form.component';
import { CalendarEventModel } from './event.model';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

export interface Ride { allDay: boolean; color: Object; primary: string; secondary: string; end: string; meta: Object; location: string; notes: string; start: string; title: string; }
export interface RideId extends Ride { id: string }

@Component({
    selector     : 'fuse-calendar',
    templateUrl  : './calendar.component.html',
    styleUrls    : ['./calendar.component.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    animations   : fuseAnimations
})
export class FuseCalendarComponent implements OnInit
{   
    view: string;
    viewDate: Date;
    events: CalendarEvent[];
    locale: string = 'nl';
    public actions: CalendarEventAction[];
    activeDayIsOpen: boolean;
    refresh: Subject<any> = new Subject();
    dialogRef: any;
    confirmDialogRef: MatDialogRef<FuseConfirmDialogComponent>;
    selectedDay: any;
    rides: Observable<RideId[]>;
    ride: Observable<Ride>;

    private ridesCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Ride>;
    private ridesDocument: AngularFirestoreDocument<Ride>;

    vehicle = [
        {value: 'vehicle-0', viewValue: 'Test 1'},
        {value: 'vehicle-1', viewValue: 'Test 2'}
    ]

    constructor(
        public dialog: MatDialog,
        private readonly db: AngularFirestore,
    )
    {
        this.view = 'month';
        this.viewDate = new Date();
        this.activeDayIsOpen = true;
        this.selectedDay = {date: startOfDay(new Date())};

        this.actions = [
            {
                label  : '<i class="material-icons s-16">edit</i>',
                onClick: ({event}: { event: CalendarEvent }): void => {
                    this.editEvent('edit', event);
                }
            },
            {
                label  : '<i class="material-icons s-16">delete</i>',
                onClick: ({event}: { event: CalendarEvent }): void => {
                    this.deleteEvent(event);
                }
            }
        ];

        /**
         * Get events from service/server
         */
         this.ridesCollection = db.collection<Ride>('rides');

         this.rides = this.ridesCollection.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
            return actions.map(a => {
            const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Ride;
            const id = a.payload.doc.id;
            return { id, ...data };
      });
    });

//        this.setEvents();
    }

    ngOnInit()
    {
        /**
         * Watch re-render-refresh for updating db
         */
//        this.refresh.subscribe(updateDB => {
//            // console.warn('REFRESH');
//            if ( updateDB )
//            {
//                // console.warn('UPDATE DB');
//                this.calendarService.updateEvents(this.events);
//            }
//        });

//        this.calendarService.onEventsUpdated.subscribe(events => {
//            this.setEvents();
//            this.refresh.next();
//        });

//        this.ridesDocument = this.db.doc('rides/id');
//        this.ride = this.ridesDocument.valueChanges();
    }

    setEvents()
    {
        //set this.events
//        this.events = this.ridesCollection.add(rides);
    }

    /**
     * Before View Renderer
     * @param {any} header
     * @param {any} body
     */
    beforeMonthViewRender({header, body})
    {
        // console.info('beforeMonthViewRender');
        /**
         * Get the selected day
         */
        const _selectedDay = body.find((_day) => {
            return _day.date.getTime() === this.selectedDay.date.getTime();
        });

        if ( _selectedDay )
        {
            /**
             * Set selectedday style
             * @type {string}
             */
            _selectedDay.cssClass = 'mat-elevation-z3';
        }

    }

    /**
     * Day clicked
     * @param {MonthViewDay} day
     */
    dayClicked(day: CalendarMonthViewDay): void
    {
        const date: Date = day.date;
        const events: CalendarEvent[] = day.events;

        if ( isSameMonth(date, this.viewDate) )
        {
            if ( (isSameDay(this.viewDate, date) && this.activeDayIsOpen === true) || events.length === 0 )
            {
                this.activeDayIsOpen = false;
            }
            else
            {
                this.activeDayIsOpen = true;
                this.viewDate = date;
            }
        }
        this.selectedDay = day;
        this.refresh.next();
    }

    /**
     * Event times changed
     * Event dropped or resized
     * @param {CalendarEvent} event
     * @param {Date} newStart
     * @param {Date} newEnd
     */
    eventTimesChanged({event, newStart, newEnd}: CalendarEventTimesChangedEvent): void
    {
        event.start = newStart;
        event.end = newEnd;
        // console.warn('Dropped or resized', event);
        this.refresh.next(true);
    }

    /**
     * Delete Event
     * @param event
     */
    deleteEvent(ride)
    {
        this.confirmDialogRef = this.dialog.open(FuseConfirmDialogComponent, {
            disableClose: false
        });

        this.confirmDialogRef.componentInstance.confirmMessage = 'Are you sure you want to delete?';

        this.confirmDialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
            if ( result )
            {
//                const eventIndex = this.events.indexOf(event);
//                this.events.splice(eventIndex, 1);
//                this.refresh.next(true);

            }
            this.confirmDialogRef = null;
        });

    }

    /**
     * Edit Event
     * @param {string} action
     * @param {CalendarEvent} event
     */
    editEvent(action: string, event: CalendarEvent)
    {
//        const eventIndex = this.events.indexOf(event);

        this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(FuseCalendarEventFormDialogComponent, {
            panelClass: 'event-form-dialog',
            data      : {
                event : event,
                action: action
            }
        });

//        console.log(event);

        this.dialogRef.afterClosed()
            .subscribe(response => {
                if ( !response )
                {
                    return;
                }
                const actionType: string = response[0];
                const formData: FormGroup = response[1];
                switch ( actionType )
                {
                    /**
                     * Save
                     */
                    case 'save':
                        var saveData: any;
//                        this.events[eventIndex] = Object.assign(this.events[eventIndex], formData.getRawValue());
                        this.refresh.next(true);

                        saveData = formData.getRawValue();
//                        saveData.start.setHours(saveData.startHour);
//                        saveData.start.setMinutes(saveData.startMinute);

                        this.ridesDocument = this.db.doc('rides/' + event.id);
                        this.ridesDocument.set(saveData);


                        break;
                    /**
                     * Delete
                     */
                    case 'delete':

//                        this.deleteEvent(event);
                        this.ridesDocument = this.db.doc('rides/' + event.id);
                        this.ridesDocument.delete();

                        break;
                }
            });
    }

    /**
     * Add Event
     */
    addEvent(): void
    {
        this.dialogRef = this.dialog.open(FuseCalendarEventFormDialogComponent, {
            panelClass: 'event-form-dialog',
            data      : {
                action: 'new',
                date  : this.selectedDay.date
            }
        });
        this.dialogRef.afterClosed()
            .subscribe((response: FormGroup) => {
                if ( !response )
                {
                    return;
                }
                const newEvent = response.getRawValue();
//                newEvent.actions = this.actions;
//                this.events.push(newEvent);
                this.refresh.next(true);
                this.ridesCollection.add(newEvent);
            });
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is exactly the error(s) in the debugging console (dev tools) ?

Comment: from what i see, it seems that `this.startHour` and `this.startMinute` are declared in the class, but never given a value, so coming as `undefined` is not that surprising

Comment: I agree, but you see... It should pick up the startHour value from the database. That's what I want. Updated question to reflect this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you haven't given any values to `startHour` or `startMinute`. Up where you have

```
startHour: string
startMinute: string
```

you're simply declaring that these variables are of type string, but not giving them a value. If you want to give them a value, you can either assign a value at the same point, like this:

```
startHour: string = 'value'
startMinute: string = 'value'
```

or in your constructor, right before you use them

```
this.event = data.event;
this.action = data.action;

this.startHour = 'value';
this.startMinute = 'value';

if ( this.action === 'edit' )
{
  this.dialogTitle = this.event.title + " - " + this.startHour + ":" + this.startMinute;
}
```

Hope this helped and good luck!

Comment: It should pick up the startHour value from the database. That's what I want. I forgot to mention that, my bad...  Updated question to reflect this.

Comment: From what I understand, you're getting from your data from `@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) private data: any`? I also see that `data` contains a `date`. If you can get the time from this, then you should able to, in your constructor, assign `startHour` and `startMinute` as such: `this.startHour = data.date.hour` and `this.startMinute = data.date.minute`, replacing hour and minute with the actual variables.

Comment: Unless I'm doing something wrong, it says it cannot read startHour when I try this.startHour = data.date.startHour.

Comment: From what I remember, Date objects have a function called `getHours()` and `getMinutes()` that you can use instead of `getTime()` to grab the hour and minute, respectively. So your declaration will probably look like `this.startHour = data.date.getHours()` and `this.startMinute = data.date.getMinutes()`, since `date` is a Date object and can use these functions.

Comment: For some reason data.date.getHours() doesn't work since it can't be read. date variable is part of the Fuse 2 library I think, but I'm not sure if it's an actual Date Object.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Fuse 2, but just based on the calendar component code you posted above, `date` seems to be a regular ol' javascript Date object.

Also, in the calendar component function `editEvent()`, in the `this.dialogRef` assignment, you don't actually include a key called `date` into `data`? You've only included an `event` and `action` key. It's likely that that's why it can't be read.

Comment: Fuse 2 has these things pre-built, meaning I have not included any of these things. I'll see what I can do though. Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: It has been solved. All I had to do was change 'this.startMinute' into 'this.event.startMinute', same for the rest. Sigh... Thanks though :)

Comment: Glad to help and hear that everything worked out! Oh okay I think I'm seeing why that worked out -- your `this.event` is a calendar event, and it looks like calendar events have minutes and hours attached to them as well. The more you know!

Answer (score 0):

Declaration and Definition are 2 different things.

```
startHour: string; // This is just declaring a variable. We haven't defined any value for it.
console.log(this.startHour); // will give undefined.

startHour: string = '';  //This is declaring + defining the variable.
console.log(this.startHour); // will give any emppty string.
```

Comment: It should pick up the startHour value from the database. That's what I want. I forgot to mention that, my bad...  Updated question to reflect this.

Comment: @WesleyOrth my advise would be to define both variables as empty string, so that they are defined while you are fetching their values from other file.

Comment: How do I fetch values from another file?

Comment: Minor note: linters would say that the second example should favor startHour = '' over having a type specified as this is already implied.

Comment: Is that more efficient? Isn't it safer to type it anyway?